# Parseval's Theorem & Unitary Operators

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In a course on Fourier Analysis, the proof of Parseval's Theorem ends on the following line:

$$\left<f,g\right>_{\mathcal{H}} = \left<\mathcal{F}f,\mathcal{F}g\right>_{\ell^2}$$

I can then show that:

$$\left<f,g\right> = \left<f,\mathcal{F}^*\mathcal{F}g\right> \implies \mathcal{F}^*\mathcal{F}g = g \implies \mathcal{F}^*\mathcal{F} = I.$$

I am wondering how this is enough to conclude that $\mathcal{F}$ is unitary, since we also need to verify that $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^* = I$.

At this point, we have not shown that $\mathcal{F}$ is invertible, but if it were I can see how uniqueness of the inverse may be used, since $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}=I$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your professor showed (in the final line) that the Fourier transform is isometric. An isometric operator is unitary if and only if it has a dense image (range). This you need to show, which might be easy or difficult depending on what properties of the Fourier transform you already know (?).

Comment: This was the first we have seen of the Fourier transform. The operator $\mathcal{F}$ was defined as $(\mathcal{F}f)_n = <f,e_n>$, where $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that $\mathcal{F}^*\mathcal{F}=I$. Then you can easily show that $\mathcal{G}f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}f(t)dt$ also satisfies $\mathcal{G}^*\mathcal{G}=I$. Finally, show that $\mathcal{F}^*=\mathcal{G}$ and you have what you want.